# SFML Multiple Room Game design, How to organize the program?

Tags: c++, game-engine, sfml

when making a game with c++ and sfml, how does one go about organizing the multiple levels? In my game there will be multiple rooms, I plan on changing the room by changing the `sf::View`, but I dont want a lengthy main.cpp that is unorganized, so do I make each room/level a separate function? Or make a class that manages the current room/level and just switches the room accordingly? Whats the best way to organize multiple levels in a sfml game? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to check out the [state pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html). Different game modes (like start menu, options menu, actual game), as well as different parts of a game (in your case: rooms) can often nicely be modeled as states.

Comment: This looks very useful, thanks I think this will help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use an enum class, thanks for link and advice domsson. My enum class and switch statements look like:

```
int windowWidth = 5000;//width of window
int windowHeight = 5000;//height of window
sf::View leveltwo(sf::FloatRect(x, y, 5000, 5000));
sf::View start(sf::FloatRect(0, 0, 2500, 1500));
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight ), "Awesome Game" );


enum Levels{
    StartRoom, LevelTwo
};
Levels room = StartRoom;
void WhatRoom(int TheLevel){
    switch (room){
        case StartRoom:
            window.setView(start);
            if (TheLevel == 2){
                room = LevelTwo;
            }

        case LevelTwo:
            window.setView(leveltwo);

    }
};
```

This is working very well.

Answer (score 1):

to create a game I really encourage you to read books on game design and SFML game architecture. https://www.sfml-dev.org/learn.php. A game is not a simple and fast program to make, and have to get a really good conception. Take your time, test the SFML and know yout environment or you will loose time.

Comment: I am reading sfml game developement by example currently, a good book but cant find a good answer to this question, and  there aren't any multiple level examples :/, if you can think of another book, please let me know. Thanks